# HP Laptop G72 with Pentium Processor - How to enable virtualization?

Tags: virtualization

Just found out my laptop has a weak Pentium processor. Can't find the option to activate virtualization in the BIOS or F9 settings. Is there something I can do about this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the option is not in the bios either it is not able to do virtualization or HP has it locked out of the bios settings, not much you can do either way.

HP is famous for locking out bios options on consumer grade notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

That processor does not support virtualization.  That's why you don't see the option in the BIOS.

http://ark.intel.com/products/42925/Intel-Pentium-Processor-T4500-1M-Cache-2_30-GHz-800-MHz-FSB